# Custom binding animation not working on a foreach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Basically I'm trying to make a number to fade out, change, and fade back in. I used a custom binding that works fine on a regular element. But inside a foreach the fade out animation won't work, the number just hides. This is the custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.slideTransition = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = valueAccessor();
    var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);

    $(element).fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(element).html(valueUnwrapped);       

        $(element).fadeIn('slow', function() {
            console.log('done');
        });
    });
  }
};
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/brunomuller/qTvs9/6/

First one is inside a foreach, getting the value from an array (fails), second one is binding the value itself (works).

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computed has an *indirect* dependency on `Value`, since you *execute* it before you put it in the returned array. This means that every time the `Value` changes, your entire array changes. this will cause the foreach to re-evaluate, probably creating a fresh `li` for it too.

If you return just the *observable* in the computed array, things work as expected:

```js
var i = 0;

function CartViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Value = ko.observable(i);

    self.centsArray = ko.computed(function() {
        return array = [
            self.Value
        ];
    });
}

ko.bindingHandlers.slideTransition = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = valueAccessor();
    var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);

    $(element).fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(element).html(valueUnwrapped);       

        $(element).fadeIn('slow', function() {
            console.log('done');
        });
    });
  }
};

var vm = new CartViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

setInterval(function () { vm.Value(++i); },  1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

foreach (not working):
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: centsArray}">
  <li><span data-bind="slideTransition: $data"></span></li>
</ul>
single (working):
<ul>
  <li><span data-bind="slideTransition: Value"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yup! That was the problem. Thanks a lot!